# Выделение объектов для верстки

Tags: вёрстка

Как в фотошопе правильно вырезать картинки используя смарт-объекты. То есть я преобразую слои в смарт-объекты, нажимаю "Выделить пиксели" и какая-то часть, например тени, не выделяется. Как довыделить оставшееся?

Answer (score 1):

из верхнего меню Layer -> Layer Based Slice (Photoshop CS3 вероятно так и в текущей версии) создадутся области, которым можно дать названия (двойной клик) которые далее станут названиями файлов, потом в диалоге Save For Web через shift можно выбрать нужные или выбрать при сохранении что-то вроде "save all user defined" не помню точно, чтобы выбрать все обозначенные области